# Call C++ DLL Sending a C# DB Connection as Argument

Tags: c#, c++, database-connection

I am migrating some code from C# to C++ and was wondering if I can transfer an existing connection from C# where there is some easy connection packages to a C++ DLL for reading and processing the results. My application connects to 5 different database types, but I streamlined everything after the query executes to using a `IDataReader` for simplification.

```
public static string OdbcExecuteQuery(OdbcConnection conn, string strQuery) {
    try {
        using (DbCommand com = new OdbcCommand(strQuery, conn)) {
                var dataResults = GenericReader(com);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    conn.Close();
    return "Success";
}

public static string MySqlExecuteQuery(MySqlConnection MyConnection, string strQuery) {
    try {
        using (DbCommand com = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, MyConnection)) {
            var dataResults = GenericReader(com);         
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    MyConnection.Close();
    return "Success";
}

// This method will read the results from any established connection
public static string GenericReader(DbCommand com, DataTable rawData = null) {
    IDataReader reader = null;
    try {
        if (rawData == null){
            com.CommandTimeout = 300;
            using (reader = com.ExecuteReader()) {
                var dtSchema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                rawData = QueryToDataTable(reader, dtSchema);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {      
    }     

    return "Success";
}
```

Is it possible to establish the connection in C# and call a function like `GenericReader` that is in a C++ DLL? I am pretty new to C++ and while I know you can pass primitives like `ints` and `strings`, not sure if you can do this.

Comment: Have you tried using a delegate so that the C++ portion can use the connection in the C# without having to be passed?

Comment: C++ cannot consume managed complex .NET types like database connections. The C++/CLI language can live in both the managed and native world, but it isn't pleasant to use. What's your motivation for using C++?

Comment: @MarkWaterman In addition to performance gains, I am trying to protect some of my code that runs through some unique methods to parse binary files which also runs through that method from being decompiled by some third parties. In addition, in C# I have all the DLL files bundled into the EXE, so if I have to re-establish those connections in C++ it will just mean a bit more work to connect to  ODBC, MySQL, MSSQL, Sybase, Pervasive databases. I only have a few weeks of C++ experience, so it seems a little daunting at times.

Comment: @BMinster I will try to look into Delegates, if you have a link, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Alan Try this for starters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/
If you prefer video examples you can look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8Blt5c-Vi4&t=1271s